# Calcular média do valor de cadastros até 100km sql

Tags: php, sql, query

estou fazendo uma consulta que traz a média dos valores, desde que a distância seja até 90km:

```
SELECT avg(valor),(6371 * acos(
 cos( radians(-23.2632227) )
 * cos( radians( lat ) )
 * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-45.9414303) )
 + sin( radians(-23.2632227) )
 * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
 )
) AS distancia
FROM fcs_prestadores
HAVING distancia < 90
```

O problema é que quando coloco o avg(valor) ele calcula a média de todos os cadastros, incluindo os que estão numa distância maior. Sem o avg(valor) ele traz certinho só os que estão dentro da distacia de 100km
sem avg(valor):

```
distancia
78.82683615218286
6.351835016010867
```

com avg(valor)

```
avg(valor)       |distancia
76.66666666666667|78.82683615218286
```

a tabela está assim:

```
id | nome|valor|lat        |lng
1  |joana|100  |-23.542746 |-46.651302
2  |maria|120  |-23.241726 |-45.883827
3  |lucia|40   |-22.8117593|-45.1786567
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tente :

```
select avg(valor)
from
(
SELECT valor,(6371 * acos(
 cos( radians(-23.2632227) )
 * cos( radians( lat ) )
 * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-45.9414303) )
 + sin( radians(-23.2632227) )
 * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
 )
) AS distancia
FROM fcs_prestadores
) virtual 
where  distancia < 90
```

Comment: funcionou perfeito, só pra saber, o que é esse virutal q vc colocou?

Comment: É um nome que ele deu à tabela em memória gerada pelo select mais interno.

Comment: alguns bds como mysql exigem que a tabela virtual tenha nome.

Comment: Olá, está funcionando certinho, mas sabe como posso fazer para trazer quem são as pessoas que atendem esse critério?
ex: trazer: avg(valor):100 | id:1, avg(valor):100 | id:2